# AES 128bit round level recommendation

Tags: aes

we don't want change standard just after every attack, now for AES 128bit blocks i think 16 round is secure, but what is best round amount ? we had attack for 7 round then 10 round and it going so on i think so is better we use a better standard. how many round you think we use is better for a long time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AES standard specifies the use of 10 rounds with 128-bit keys. Anything other than this is, by definition, not AES. There are no known effective attacks against standard AES-128.

Comment: but here they recommended 16 round or more for 128bit blocks : https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html

Comment: @mary Schneier said, more or less, if he would be the one to standardize a new encryption algorithm based on the current AES algorithm, he would chose more conservative round counts. But even if this were done, the resulting algorithm certainly would get a new name, not AES-128, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann♦ so we use 16 round for 128blocks or not ? (if not i'm really worry about new attacks in the future because as Schneier said attacks just getting better not worst )

Comment: @mary For now, use the standard AES-128 (with 10 rounds). When someone standardizes a variant with 16 rounds (and there are implementations available in common crypto libraries), you can think about switching to that.

Comment: There is an easy way to get 14 rounds with 128 bit blocks: It's called AES-256. Expanding a 128 bit key into a 256 bit key, if you want to do so, is easy.

Comment: Can you do this without exposing yourself to the weakened AES-256 key schedule? That's the whole reason Schneier advocates using AES-128 in the first place, as well as increasing the number of rounds of each variant.

Comment: @StephenTouset just don't use related keys, to avoid related key attacks on AES-256. In other words, just don't base your hash function on it.

Comment: Mary, if there is ever a need to change the number of rounds, then it is very likely that a different symmetric algorithm is used instead.

Comment: @owlstead so Schneier saying crap ?

Comment: No, not that, but AES has not such a good track record regarding side channel attacks, the key schedule is a bit wobbly ... in other words, we have advanced a few years. None of the second round candidates of SHA-3 were based on AES. But I don't have a crystal ball either.

Comment: Note that Schneier suggest that *NIST* update the AES spec to use a greater number of rounds. *Not* that individuals should reimplement their own higher-round versions of AES. Note also that he doesn't recommend existing implementations move away from AES-256. Let the cryptographers do what cryptographers do best — when there's genuine cause for alarm, you will hear about it.